# Java Control Panel quit unexpectedly while using the libjvm.dylib plug-in | MacOSX

Tags: macos, java, java-7

I install newest jdk from oracle pages 7u10. When I had java6 everything was ok, but now i cannot run netbeans or java preferences (from System Preferences) because I have got error:
Java Control Panel quit unexpectedly while using the libjvm.dylib plug-in.

I need some help because I don't see any solution in google;/

Comment: Did you check to see whether you have the latest netbeans which is compatible with Java 1.7?

Comment: I have got last netbeans version so it is support java7

Comment: I remove java 7 form my system and It looks good now. Probably problem is with Java Oracle Distribution for MacOSX.

Answer (score 1):

Running this patch on 10.7.5 solved the problem : http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-22830
although it is mentioned that is only works on 10.8